# How to print data if pattern is found in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file (A.txt ; sep=",") :

```
kit
Software Version =
Date And Time of Export =
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
,,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01,,,
,,neg5,A02,Neg Ctrl-01,,,
,,pos6,A03,Pos Ctrl-01,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
*reporting.
```

And I want to print in the "Interpretive Result" column a result if the "Sample Type" column contain a pattern :
"Patient" if "Unkn" ;  "NC" if "Neg" ;  "PC" if "Pos".
In order to have the following output (B.txt ; sep=","):

```
kit
Software Version =
Date And Time of Export =
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
,,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01,,Patient,,
,,neg5,A02,Neg Ctrl-01,,NC,,
,,pos6,A03,Pos Ctrl-01,,PC,,
,,,,,,,,,,
*reporting.
```

I've try things like  :

```
awk -F',' -v OFS="," '(NR>1 && $5="Unkn"*){print ...}' A.txt > B.txt
```

But I don't manage to solved the issue.
Can someone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: `$5="Unkn"` is an assignment, not a comparison `$5=="Unkn"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented above, you need `==` for comparison. But compare fields with regexes using the `~` operator, that is what it was made for.

**`pat.awk`**:

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
$5 ~ /Unkn/{$7="Patient,"}
$5 ~ /Neg/{$7="NC,"}
$5 ~ /Pos/{$7="PC,"}
{print}
```

```
$ awk -f pat.awk A.txt 
kit
Software Version =
Date And Time of Export =
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
,,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01,,Patient,,
,,neg5,A02,Neg Ctrl-01,,NC,,
,,pos6,A03,Pos Ctrl-01,,PC,,
,,,,,,,,,,
*reporting.
```

If you prefer the one-liner:

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '$5~/Unkn/{$7="Patient,"}$5~/Neg/{$7="NC,"}$5~/Pos/{$7="PC,"}1' A.txt
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know about the "~" assignation

Comment: @Quasimodo to make it "foolproof", you may want to consider anchoring the RegExps to the beginning of the field (`$5 ~ /^Unkn/`), although I acknowledge the OP only said that the column "contains" a pattern ...

Comment: @AdminBee Thank you for your comment. Yes, I thought better not to anchor it because of "contains".